# Conditional Mirroring of A Column to another Column

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck trying to figure out this problem. To simplify what I am trying to do, I am basically trying to make Column F an drop down list (Ex:Apples, Bananas, Oranges, Mango, etc), where the user can choose multiple items from the drop down list with a line break, and whatever drop down item chosen in Column F would “mirror” or replicate into Column G. So for example:

Column F:

```
Apples

Bananas

Oranges
```

And in Column G:

```
Apples

Bananas

Oranges
```

Now, in Column G, I need to be able to write notes in for each item chosen in F. So with the example above:

Column G:

```
Apples: Round and Red

Bananas: Long and Yellow

Oranges: Round and Orange
```

I do not want whatever comments I write in Column G to replicate into Column F.
What I'm having trouble with is when I need to add another item in to Column F, for example Mango, the mirroring effect recopies all the drop down items previously selected in Column F.
For example:

Column F:

```
Apples

Bananas

Oranges

Mango (*newly added*)
```

Column G:

```
Apples: Round and Red

Bananas: Long and Yellow

Oranges: Round and Orange

Apples

Bananas

Oranges

Mango
```

It does this re-mirroring every time you add an item in. I basically need the VBA code to just add Mango and not re-mirror the previous drop down items into Column G. 
Note: If I take out an item in Column F, I don’t need the item and the comment to disappear from Column G. I just need the additions from Column F to appear into Column G without the other items reappearing.

Below is my code so far:

```
Private Sub
Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As  Range)
    Dim oldVal As String, newVal     As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim bMatch As Boolean
    Dim vItems As Variant


    If Target.Count > 1 Or _
        Target.Column <> 6 Then GoTo exitHandler


    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeSameValidation).Cells.Count = 0 _
        Then Exit Sub
    On Error GoTo exitHandler


    Application.EnableEvents = False
    newVal = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    oldVal = Target.Value
    Target.Value = newVal


    If oldVal = "" Or newVal = "" Then GoTo exitHandler


    vItems = Split(oldVal, vbNewLine)
    For i = 0 To UBound(vItems)
          If vItems(i) = newVal Then
              bMatch = True
              vItems(i) = "~Filter Out~"
          End If
    Next i
    If bMatch Then  'remove item
          vItems = Filter(vItems, "~Filter Out~", Include:=False, _
              Compare:=vbTextCompare)
          Target.Value = Join(vItems, vbNewLine)
    Else   'append item
        Target.Value = oldVal & vbNewLine & newVal
    End If

If Target.Column = 6 Then 'it's a column F value that changed
Dim OnlyAddNew As Boolean
OnlyAddNew = InStr(1, Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1), Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column), vbTextCompare) > 0
If OnlyAddNew = True Then
Selection.clearcontent
End If
If OnlyAddNew = False Then
Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1) = Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1) & vbNewLine & Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)
End If
End If



exitHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I hope I explained everything well. Please comment if you do not understand my goal/my actions.
I sincerely appreciate your help in advance.

---

Additional Question: Mirroring Column F into Column H and I as well:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim strBreak As String
Dim strAddVal As String
Dim strOldChosen As String
Dim strNewChosen As String
Dim strOldVal As String
Dim strOldOldVal As String
Dim strOldOldOldVal As String
Dim strNewVal As String
Dim blnAddVal As Boolean
Dim arrLines() As String

    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 6 Then
            If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeSameValidation).Cells.Count > 0 Then
                If Not IsNull(Target.Value) And Target.Value <> "" Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    strAddVal = Target.Value
                    strOldVal = Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Value
                    strOldOldVal = Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 2).Value
                    strOldOldOldVal = Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 3).Value
                    Application.Undo
                    strOldChosen = Target.Value

                    ' Process Chosen Values (F)
                    strBreak = ""
                    blnAddVal = True
                    strNewChosen = ""
                    If strOldChosen <> "" Then
                        arrLines = Split(strOldChosen, vbLf, , vbTextCompare)
                        For Each strLine In arrLines
                            If strLine = strAddVal Then
                                blnAddVal = False
                            Else
                                strNewChosen = strNewChosen & strBreak & strLine
                                If strBreak = "" Then strBreak = vbLf
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                    If blnAddVal = True Then
                        strNewChosen = strNewChosen & strBreak & strAddVal
                    End If
                    Target.Value = strNewChosen

                    ' Process Mirrored Values (G)
                    strBreak = ""
                    blnAddVal = True
                    If strOldVal <> "" Then
                        strBreak = vbLf
                        arrLines = Split(strOldVal, vbLf, , vbTextCompare)
                        Dim i As Integer
                        i = 1
                        For Each strLine In arrLines
                            If strLine Like (strAddVal & "*") Then
                                blnAddVal = False
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                    If blnAddVal = True Then
                        strNewVal = strOldVal & strBreak & strAddVal
                        Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Value = strNewVal
                    End If
                End If
                     ' Process Mirrored Values (H)
                    strBreak = ""
                    blnAddVal = True
                    If strOldVal <> "" Then
                        strBreak = vbLf
                        arrLines = Split(strOldOldVal, vbLf, , vbTextCompare)
                        Dim y As Integer
                        y = 1
                        For Each strLine In arrLines
                            If strLine Like (strAddVal & "*") Then
                                blnAddVal = False
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                    If blnAddVal = True Then
                        strNewVal = strOldOldVal & strBreak & strAddVal
                        Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 2).Value = strNewVal
                    End If
                End If
                     ' Process Mirrored Values (i)
                    strBreak = ""
                    blnAddVal = True
                    If strOldVal <> "" Then
                        strBreak = vbLf
                        arrLines = Split(strOldOldOldVal, vbLf, , vbTextCompare)
                        Dim r As Integer
                        r = 1
                        For Each strLine In arrLines
                            If strLine Like (strAddVal & "*") Then
                                blnAddVal = False
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                    If blnAddVal = True Then
                        strNewVal = strOldOldOldVal & strBreak & strAddVal
                        Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 3).Value = strNewVal
                    End If
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, how do you implement a drop-down in column F is it through Data Validation? And is there any chance to see the screenshot of how it should look like, 'cos I can't understand what "mirroring" is?

Comment: Yes, for F, I used data validation. I’ll also post a picture, but when I say “mirroring”, I mean I need each cell in F to copy&paste or replicate the items selected in F into G. So if I choose apples, bananas, oranges in F, I need apples, bananas, oranges to appear in G, just as it appears in F. A carbon copy of the cells in F, but I just need to be able to edit or comment in the cells in G for each item selected in F that appears in G. I also need to be able to add items in F after I make the comments in G, and make that newly selected item in F to appear in G. I hope that wasn’t confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give something like this a try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim strBreak As String
Dim strAddVal As String
Dim strOldChosen As String
Dim strNewChosen As String
Dim strOldVal As String
Dim strNewVal As String
Dim blnAddVal As Boolean
Dim arrLines() As String

    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 6 Then
            If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeSameValidation).Cells.Count > 0 Then
                If Not IsNull(Target.Value) And Target.Value <> "" Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    strAddVal = Target.Value
                    strOldVal = Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Value
                    Application.Undo
                    strOldChosen = Target.Value

                    ' Process Chosen Values (F)
                    strBreak = ""
                    blnAddVal = True
                    strNewChosen = ""
                    If strOldChosen <> "" Then
                        arrLines = Split(strOldChosen, vbLf, , vbTextCompare)
                        For Each strLine In arrLines
                            If strLine = strAddVal Then
                                blnAddVal = False
                            Else
                                strNewChosen = strNewChosen & strBreak & strLine
                                If strBreak = "" Then strBreak = vbLf
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                    If blnAddVal = True Then
                        strNewChosen = strNewChosen & strBreak & strAddVal
                    End If
                    Target.Value = strNewChosen

                    ' Process Mirrored Values (G)
                    strBreak = ""
                    blnAddVal = True
                    If strOldVal <> "" Then
                        strBreak = vbLf
                        arrLines = Split(strOldVal, vbLf, , vbTextCompare)
                        Dim i As Integer
                        i = 1
                        For Each strLine In arrLines
                            If strLine Like (strAddVal & "*") Then
                                blnAddVal = False
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                    If blnAddVal = True Then
                        strNewVal = strOldVal & strBreak & strAddVal
                        Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Value = strNewVal
                    End If
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi EMF, Thank you so much for your comment. I tried inputting your code into the macro, and the issue at hand got fixed (Thank you!) When you select an item in F, the code will not override any comments in G and only newly added items appear in G as well without any duplication/re-mirroring of the previously selected items. But the issue now is, although the column G works great, Column F can no longer select multiple drop down items. Instead of being able to select Apples, Bananas, and Oranges, one can only select one of the three. But Interestingly enough, Column G functions correctly.

Comment: @237Fan: Column G gets updated each time a selection is made, adding the most recent selection to the existing content, if it is not already present. Data validation lists don't allow multiple selections. Are you using something like https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/ to fake a multiselect dropdown list? If so, let me know and I'll add a section to my code to handle that.

Comment: Yes! I apologize for not clarifying that part. I actually used a modified version of what I found from the site you provided (The VBA Code to allow Multiple Selections in a Drop-down List (without repetition)): I found a modified version of this code where if you select multiple dropdown items such as Apples, Bananas, and Oranges for example, and I didn't want Apples anymore, I would click Apples again in the dropdown, and it would deselect Apples from the list. This is shown in the top part of the code I posted. If you wouldn't mind, I would like this included in the code, Thank you!

Comment: @237Fan: I edited my answer to accommodate the multiselect dropdown hack and to handle Excel's linefeed behavior.

Comment: Thank you very, very much! I've tried the code couple times and it works great. I can not thank you enough.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for helping me with this post. If you have time, I actually had another question regarding this code. I now need to replicate the Column F to G "Re-Mirroring" with Column H and I as well. So if I choose an item in F, all three G, H, and I would also "mirror" the chosen item from F. I thought this would be a fairly simple change by copying "  'Process Mirrored Values (G)  " section of the code, and just adding a new Dim instead of strOldVal and new integer instead of i for Column H and I.  (Continued...)

Comment: This re-copying this code section worked to a certain extent: Now if I select items in F, the item will populate in Column G, H, and I. But now every time I delete the whole list in a certain cell in column F, all items and comments are deleted in column H and I as well. Strangely enough, Column G does not get affected with the deletion in F. I was wondering if you knew a way to stop Column H and I to stop deleting if I delete out F, and get the two columns to remain like Column G.

Comment: I have also posted the new code in the original post, please let me know if you need clarifications or if you have any questions. Thank you very very much

Comment: I'm not in a place when I can test this right now, but just at a glance, I see that you missed updating a couple of variables in the copies. Fix the two places where the copies still say "If strOldVal <> "" Then" and let me know if that changes the behavior.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, unaccepting the answer because you changed the parameters of your question after the fact is not the way to inspire people to provide additional help. Something to consider if you intend to keep using StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I apologize about that, I'm very new to this site, and I was not aware that if I edit the original question/code, the answer acceptance seem to not stay. Was not my intention to undermine, I apologize about that!